# LinkedList Rotation with k value

Tags: swift, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, rotation

To rotate a linked list with k nodes, I try an approach where I traverse the list using non-optional node. The code have error at the step where I "chain" the list

The algorithm is simple

1. Use variable "fast", start from head and move to index k off the head
2. Use variable "slow" starting from head
3. Concurrenly move "fast" and "slow"
4. When "fast" hit end of list, star the chaining (setting the last node's next to the current head) and assign new head node

```swift
public class ListNode {
    public var value: Int
    public var next: ListNode?
    public init(value: Int, next: ListNode? = nil) {
        self.value =  value
        self.next = next
    }
}

extension ListNode: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        guard let next = next else {
            return "\(value)"
        }
        return "\(value) -> " + String(describing: next) + " "
    }
}

func rotateRight(_ head: ListNode?, _ k: Int) -> ListNode? {

    guard let head = head else { return nil }

    var fast = head
    var slow = head

    for _ in 0..<k where fast.next != nil {
        fast = fast.next!
    }

    while fast.next != nil {
        slow = slow.next!
        fast = fast.next!
        print("fast \(fast.value) slow \(slow.value)")
    }

    let new_head = slow.next!
    slow.next = nil
    fast.next = head

    return new_head
}

let node: ListNode = {
    let one = ListNode(value: 1)
    let two = ListNode(value: 2)
    let three = ListNode(value: 3)
    let four = ListNode(value: 4)
    let five = ListNode(value: 5)
    one.next = two
    two.next = three
    three.next = four
    four.next = five
    five.next = nil
    return one
}()

print(node.description)
rotateRight(node, 3)
print(node.description)
```

I've got "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee108af98)." when running on Playground

The bug seem to be at line fast.next = head, but I don't get what is wrong with this logic!

Comment: (1) What is the error you get?  (2) How do you get to that code?  I don't see where you've called rotateRight.  (3) You say you don't see what's wrong, but you haven't included the instrumentation and output from your debugging runs.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: What will your code do if somebody asks you to rotate the list 3 positions, but there are only 2 nodes in the list?

Comment: @JimMischel, yes that case not covered

Comment: @Prune i have added the part where I use the code i.e rotateRight

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do something with the value returned by `rotateRight`?

Comment: Copying and pasting the code in a playground, I don't get any errors

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted some parts of your code to handle any positive rotation, even if it's bigger than the length of the list:

```
func rotateRight(_ head: ListNode?, by k: Int) -> ListNode? {
    guard let head = head else { return nil }
    if k == 0 { return head }

    var fast = head
    var slow = head
    var count = 1

    for _ in 0..<k where fast.next != nil {
        fast = fast.next!
        count += 1
    }

    // If k is greater than (or equal to) the length of the list 
    if count <= k {      
        count = k % count  
        // If k is a multiple of the length of the list         
        if count == 0 { return head }
        fast = head
        for _ in 0..<count where fast.next != nil {
            fast = fast.next!
        }
    }

    while fast.next != nil {
        slow = slow.next!
        fast = fast.next!
    }

    let new_head = slow.next!
    slow.next = nil
    fast.next = head

    return new_head
}
```

Using the same example in your code:

```
print("** Before **")
print(node)
let newList = rotateRight(node, by: 11)
print("\n** After **")
print(newList!)
```

It prints:

> ```
> ** Before **
> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5    
>
> ** After **
> 5 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
> ```